# Laravel 5.2 : How to retrieve data from database in one to one eloquent relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to access data for a particular user and update the data.As the database is empty for that reason when i wanted to go to the update page for updating the data it's showing the following error.

> ErrorException in 14cfe21a93ffc779c1e985ab027ee400af4e7d8b.php line
>   12: Trying to get property of non-object (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\protfolio\resources\views\update.blade.php)

I'm using one to one  eloquent relationship.
single user can create his own profile and update the profile.

My User Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];


    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

     public function post()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Post'); //Profile is your profile model
    }
}
```

My Post Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
      protected $fillable = [
    'first_name', 'middle_name', 'last_name','gender',                            'dob','nationality','nid','email','phone_no','about_me'
];
     public function user()
    {
       return $this->belongsTo('App\User'); //Profile is your profile model
    }
}
```

Here is the route:

```
<?php

    Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {

    Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
    })->name('home');

    Route::get('/dashboard', [
    'uses' =>'PostController@getDashboard',
    'as' => 'dashboard',
    'middleware' => 'auth'
    ]);

    Route::post('/update',[
    'uses'=>'PostController@postUpdate',
    'as' => 'update',
    'middleware' =>'auth'
    ]);

    Route::get('/account',[
    'uses' => 'UserController@getAccount',
    'as' =>'account',
     'middleware' =>'auth'
    ]); 

  Route::get('/create',[
    'uses' => 'UserController@getCreate',
    'as' =>'create',
    'middleware' =>'auth'
    ]);

  Route::post('/save',[
    'uses'=>'PostController@postCreate',
    'as' =>'save'

    ]);

});
```

My Post Controller:

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Illuminate\Http\Response;
    use App\Http\Requests;
    use App\Post;
    use App\User;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;

    class PostController extends Controller
    {
        public function getDashboard()
   {        
      $posts = DB::table('posts')->where('id', Auth::user()->id);     
          return view('dashboard',['posts'=>$posts]);  
    }
        public function postUpdate(Request $request)
    {
          $this->validate($request,[
            'first_name'=> 'required|max:120',
            'middle_name'=> 'required|max:120',
            'last_name' => 'required|max:120',
            'gender'=> 'required',
            'dob'=>'required',
            'nationality'=>'required',
            'nid'=>'required',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
            'phone_no'=>'required',
            'about_me'=>'required',
            ]);
     //   $data =fill($request->all());
      $data = $request->only('first_name', 'middle_name', 'last_name',
       'gender', 'dob', 'nationality', 'nid', 'email', 'phone_no', 'about_me');
       $request->user()->post()->update($data) ;  
        return redirect()->route('dashboard');
       }        
    }
```

And here is the update.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')
     @include('includes.message-block')
     <div class="container" >
            <h3> Update Profile </h3>
        {!! Form::open(array('route' => 'update','class'=>'form-horizontal','method'=>'POST'))  !!}
    {{--    {!! Form::token(); !!}
        {!!   csrf_field() ; !!} --}}
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>First Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="first_name" class="form-control"   value="{{$posts->first()->first_name}}">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Middle Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="middle_name" class="form-control"  value="{{$posts->first()->middle_name}}">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Last Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="last_name" class="form-control"   value="{{$posts->first()->last_name}}">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Gender</label>
                <select class="form-control" name="gender" value="{{$posts->first()->gender}}">
                    <option>Male</option>
                    <option>Female</option>     
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label> Date Of Birth</label>  
                <input type="date" name="dob" class="form-control"  value="{{$posts->first()->dob}}">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Nationality</label>
                <input type="text" name="nationality" class="form-control"   value="{{$posts->first()->nationality}}">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>NID</label>
                <input type="text" name="nid" class="form-control"   value="{{$posts->first()->nid}}">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Email</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control"   value="{{$posts->first()->email}}">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Phone</label>
                <input type="text" name="phone_no" class="form-control"   value="{{$posts->first()->phone_no}}">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>About Me</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" name="about_me"  rows="3">{{$posts->first()->about_me}}</textarea>
            </div>


            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        {!! Form::close() !!}
        </div>

 @endsection
```

Comment: Where is the method for your `update.blade.php` view ? Please post the code of the `routes.php` file.

Comment: you are doing query from post table,is post table have first_name,last_name etc which you are using in form?May be you are doing populate wrong index

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using this:

```
{!! Form::open(array('route' => 'update','class'=>'form-horizontal','method'=>'POST'))  !!}
```

Use this:

```
{!! Form::model($posts, array('route' => 'update','class'=>'form-horizontal','method'=>'POST'))  !!}
```

If you use like above, no need to set the manually into the `form`. Now remove the `value` attribute from all input fields.

In Controller:

```
public function getDashboard()
{        
    $posts = \DB::table('posts')->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->first();     
    return view('dashboard.update', compact('posts'));  //If the `update.blade.php` is into the `dashboard` directory.
}
```

Comment: sorry bro. the problem still remains same! 
See I have no database for that user.So it's should show empty value.Instead of it it's showing the above error.

Comment: You must have a table for `users` to define a `One to One` relation.

Comment: I defined in my model only.

Comment: If you don't have any `users` table, how did you make the authentication system ? How does the `Auth::user()->id` exist ?

Comment: Yo bro, I do have user table. As i said earlier i already defined user model.And you might have known php artisan make:model User  -m  can automatic create the user table also. And without that table i can't enter into my project also.  


should I post the migration table for you also?

Comment: Post the code of migration files and also check the output of this `dd(Auth::user());` and let me know the output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108138/discussion-between-x69-and-md-mahfuzur-rahman).